# Share module image on facebook in joomla

Tags: facebook, joomla, joomla-module

I tried to share an image which in my custom module on facebook.

This is the code of the module

```
<div class="col-md-4 box thumbnail" >
<img src="../Cotton/modules/mod_coco/images/CoCo2.jpg">
  <span class="art-hvr" >
    <div class="row">
      <img class="hover"  src="../Cotton/modules/mod_coco/images/hover_05.jpg">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6  pro-name">Product name</div>
            <div class="col-md-6 social-two">
                <img class="smallscreen" src="../modules/mod_new/images/fb.png">
                <img class="smallscreen" src="../modules/mod_new/images/pin.png">
                <img class="smallscreen" src="../modules/mod_new/images/twt.png">
                <img class="smallscreen" src="../modules/mod_new/images/g+.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10  pro-des">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                    Donec malesuada elit felis, ut ornare massa euismod sit amet. Nam malesuada commodo
                    lectus, ut elementum justo laoreet sit amet. Nam diam massa, adipiscing non ultricies eget, condimentum sed velit. </div>
            </div>
      </img>
    </div>
</span>
</div>
```

I want to share CoCo2.jpg image when click the fb.png image.

Can any one know any plugin or any way to do this?

Comment: Why are you wrapping a massive block of code within an `<img>` tag? I would seriously think about re-writing what you have here, as no offense but it's terrible.

Comment: on one image there are another icons and descriptions thats why i did it.

Comment: In which case created a wrapper. Have a look at the structure in this example: http://getuikit.com/docs/thumbnail.html It's a much better approach. Your method is not correct HTML markup